# pyspark Cassandra connector

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, pyspark, connector

I have to install pyspark-cassandra-connector which available in https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra 
but I faced huge problems and errors and no supported document regarding to spark with python which called pyspark!!!
I want to know is pyspark-cassandra-connector package is depricated or something else?. Also, I need clear step-by-step tutorials for git clone pyspark-cassandra-connector package, installation and import it in pyspark shell and make successful connection with cassandra and make transactions, building tables or keyspaces via pyspark and effect on it.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1** (spark-cassandra-connector)

1. Use below command to start pyspark shell by using spark-cassandra-connector

   ```
   pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.2
   ```
2. Now you can import modules
3. Read data from cassandra table "emp" and keyspace "test" as

   ```
   spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="emp", keyspace="test").load().show()
   ```

**Approach 2** (pyspark-cassandra)

1. Use below command to start pyspark shell by using pyspark-cassandra

   ```
   pyspark --packages anguenot/pyspark-cassandra:2.4.0
   ```
2. Read data from cassandra table "emp" and keyspace "test" as

   ```
   spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="emp", keyspace="test").load().show()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link helps you in your task

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/#documentation

The Link in your question points to a repository where the build are failing.
It also has a link to the above repository.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:
Either using pyspark or spark-shell

#1 pyspark:
Steps to follow:

1. pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark: spark-cassandra-connector_2.11: 2.4.2
2. df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").option("keyspace":"<keyspace_name>").option("table":"<table_name>").load

Note: this will create a dataframe on which you can perform further oprations

3. try agg(),select(),show(),etc. methods or tab after 'df.', which will show you available options
   example: df.select(sum("<column_name>")).show()

#2 spark-shell:

1. spark --packages or
2. use above package or use a connector jar file with spark-shell

above (#1)steps will work exactly the same, but just use 'val' to create variable
ex. val df = read.format().load()

Note : use ':paste' option in scala to write multiple lines or to paste your code

#3 Steps to download spark-cassandra-connector:

1. download the spark-cassandra-connector by cloning https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector.git
2. cd to the spark-cassandra-connector
3. ./sbt/sbt assembly
4. this will download the spark-cassandra-connector and will put them into 'project' folder
5. use spark-shell
6. all set
   Cheers !

Comment: you don't need to compile connector yourself. you just need to use already packaged version from Maven Central

Answer (score -2):

you can use this to connect to cassandra

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

you can read like this
if you have  keyspace called test and a table called my_table

```
val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "my_table")
test_spark_rdd.first
```